# Remove the current node in cloud function in Firebase onWrite

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to do a cloud function on the added node on firebase and delete it once the function is over. `then((event)=>event.remove())` does not work in the following code.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/Q/{pushId}')
  .onWrite(event => {

      const to = event.data.child("to").val();
      const message = event.data.child("m").val();

      const messageTime = Date.now()*-1;
      const messageFromName = event.data.child('fromName').val();

    var updateMessage = {};
    for (var toCounter in to) {
      updateMessage[`/${to[toCounter]}/c/${messageTime}`] = message;
      updateMessage[`/${to[toCounter]}/i/fName`] = messageFromName;

    }

     admin.database().ref().update(updateMessage).then((event)=>event.remove());


  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `remove()` on the reference or parent's reference.

`event.data.ref.parent.remove();` or `event.data.ref.remove();`

---

So if you have:

```
"-kwwe323r22g222322": {
    "apples": "apples"
}
```

Your data would be:

`{"apples":"apples"}`

and `event.data.ref` would be:

`-kwwe323r22g222322`.